# Adjectives used to describe a person who only respects rich people

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, british-english

I don't know the adjective used to describe a person who **only respects rich people or money**.

Comment: I can only think if 'snobbish', but that relates to social prestige rather than simply wealth.

Comment: limousine liberals?

Comment: a one word adj?  gonna be a tuff one.

Comment: Is the person to be described also wealthy? If not, "sycophantic" or "toadying" might be on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elitist

> **ELITIST**
>
> giving special treatment and advantages to wealthy and powerful people